# Seeking lists (in array form) of latitude, longitudes for streets and other places?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am trying to get an array of latitude and longitudes so that I can test line making on an app. My issue though is finding lists (in form of array) of latitude and longitude. This is an example of what I am looking for:

```
[ [ 37.33523566, -122.03254863], [ 37.33521504, -122.03254905 ], [ 37.33519572, -122.0325498 ], [ 37.33517518, -122.03255055 ], [ 37.33515083, -122.03255349 ], [ 37.3351212, -122.03256229 ], [ 37.33507162, -122.0326037 ], [ 37.33503868, -122.03265072 ], [ 37.33500926, -122.03272188 ], [ 37.33497737, -122.03281282 ], [ 37.33494812, -122.0329212 ], [ 37.33492222, -122.03304215 ], [ 37.33489242, -122.03318372 ], [ 37.33485843, -122.03334424 ], [ 37.33482105, -122.03350886 ], [ 37.33477977, -122.03369603 ], [ 37.33474691, -122.03389325 ], [ 37.33470894, -122.03411085 ], [ 37.33467638, -122.03432425 ], [ 37.33464561, -122.03455442 ], [ 37.33461946, -122.03478727 ], [ 37.33460316, -122.0350347 ], [ 37.33458564, -122.03529395 ], [ 37.3345628, -122.03556217 ], [ 37.3345597, -122.03583308 ], [ 37.33454847, -122.03611286 ], [ 37.33454218, -122.03638578 ], [ 37.33454235, -122.03666775 ], [ 37.33453849, -122.03695223 ], [ 37.33453874, -122.03724626 ], [ 37.33453652, -122.03753997 ], [ 37.33452613, -122.03783266 ], [ 37.33451917, -122.03813827 ], [ 37.33451284, -122.03845141 ], [ 37.33450379, -122.03875937 ], [ 37.33449629, -122.03908048 ], [ 37.33448791, -122.03941089 ], [ 37.33447622, -122.0397398 ], [ 37.33447068, -122.04007348 ], [ 37.33446519, -122.04041597 ], [ 37.3344584, -122.04077831 ], [ 37.33445283, -122.04113765 ], [ 37.3344499, -122.04149924 ], [ 37.33444604, -122.04187567 ], [ 37.33444843, -122.04226334 ], [ 37.33444952, -122.04265083 ], [ 37.33445363, -122.04302852 ], [ 37.33445945, -122.04342255 ], [ 37.33446146, -122.04380955 ], [ 37.33445832, -122.04420408 ], [ 37.33445442, -122.04458579 ], [ 37.33444763, -122.04496063 ], [ 37.33444244, -122.045341 ], [ 37.33443657, -122.04571727 ], [ 37.33441708, -122.04607568 ], [ 37.3343947, -122.04644121 ], [ 37.33436235, -122.04681002 ], [ 37.33431797, -122.04716524 ], [ 37.33426985, -122.04751058 ], [ 37.33420971, -122.04784191 ], [ 37.33414287, -122.04818683 ], [ 37.33406324, -122.04853007 ], [ 37.33398776, -122.04886543 ], [ 37.33390604, -122.04921638 ], [ 37.3338288, -122.04956959 ], [ 37.33375445, -122.04992666 ], [ 37.33367998, -122.05028306 ], [ 37.33360693, -122.05063996 ], [ 37.33352458, -122.05100549 ], [ 37.33344889, -122.05137547 ], [ 37.33336511, -122.05174034 ], [ 37.33328787, -122.05209673 ], [ 37.33321101, -122.05246948 ], [ 37.33313411, -122.05283635 ], [ 37.33305632, -122.05318781 ], [ 37.33298105, -122.0535463 ], [ 37.33290406, -122.05391527 ], [ 37.33282486, -122.05427997 ], [ 37.33275353, -122.05462472 ], [ 37.33268517, -122.05498531 ], [ 37.33260475, -122.05535361 ], [ 37.33252881, -122.05571688 ], [ 37.33245639, -122.05608208 ], [ 37.33238246, -122.05644652 ], [ 37.33236209, -122.05682698 ], [ 37.33232211, -122.05719234 ], [ 37.33229772, -122.05757204 ], [ 37.332289, -122.05795133 ], [ 37.33228724, -122.05833354 ], [ 37.33230505, -122.05871525 ], [ 37.33233606, -122.05909629 ], [ 37.33238246, -122.0594718 ], [ 37.33244004, -122.05984991 ], [ 37.33251376, -122.06021989 ], [ 37.33260198, -122.06059221 ], [ 37.33270432, -122.06095339 ], [ 37.33282574, -122.06131389 ], [ 37.3329513, -122.06167465 ], [ 37.33307736, -122.06203541 ], [ 37.33320782, -122.06239181 ], [ 37.33333498, -122.06274686 ], [ 37.33346293, -122.06310662 ], [ 37.33358639, -122.06346075 ], [ 37.33370957, -122.06381723 ], [ 37.33383844, -122.06417204 ], [ 37.33395407, -122.06452986 ], [ 37.33405917, -122.06489607 ], [ 37.33414928, -122.06526437 ], [ 37.33422447, -122.06562781 ], [ 37.33429383, -122.06600055 ], [ 37.33435409, -122.06636961 ], [ 37.33440019, -122.06674461 ], [ 37.33442928, -122.06711736 ], [ 37.3344465, -122.06749672 ], [ 37.3344543, -122.06787986 ], [ 37.33444654, -122.06826065 ], [ 37.33442613, -122.06864035 ], [ 37.33439537, -122.06901468 ], [ 37.33435661, -122.06939204 ], [ 37.33430397, -122.06976336 ], [ 37.33424182, -122.07013275 ], [ 37.33417438, -122.07050306 ], [ 37.33410968, -122.07087404 ], [ 37.33403923, -122.07123245 ], [ 37.33396475, -122.07160897 ], [ 37.33389384, -122.07197743 ], [ 37.33382775, -122.07235512 ], [ 37.33375801, -122.07272963 ], [ 37.33369775, -122.07309474 ], [ 37.33363907, -122.07346522 ], [ 37.33359159, -122.07381886 ], [ 37.33355651, -122.07417592 ], [ 37.33353728, -122.07453283 ], [ 37.33353065, -122.07488445 ], [ 37.33353363, -122.07523112 ], [ 37.33355228, -122.07558936 ], [ 37.33358308, -122.07595104 ], [ 37.33362663, -122.0763056 ], [ 37.33368006, -122.07665613 ], [ 37.33374934, -122.07700482 ], [ 37.33382825, -122.07735141 ], [ 37.33392322, -122.07769942 ], [ 37.33402871, -122.07804543 ], [ 37.33415037, -122.07838406 ], [ 37.3342805, -122.07872034 ], [ 37.33442102, -122.07904631 ], [ 37.33457244, -122.0793639 ], [ 37.33473735, -122.0796747 ], [ 37.33492184, -122.07997503 ], [ 37.33511119, -122.08026077 ], [ 37.33531428, -122.08054952 ], [ 37.33552177, -122.08082252 ], [ 37.33573891, -122.08110667 ], [ 37.33595575, -122.08138403 ], [ 37.33617167, -122.08165962 ], [ 37.33638536, -122.08193111 ], [ 37.33659906, -122.08220411 ], [ 37.33680278, -122.08247812 ], [ 37.3370055, -122.0827595 ], [ 37.33720302, -122.08304213 ], [ 37.3373963, -122.08332863 ], [ 37.33758129, -122.08362627 ], [ 37.33775509, -122.08392617 ], [ 37.33793145, -122.0842275 ], [ 37.33810893, -122.08454124 ], [ 37.3382842, -122.08484542 ], [ 37.3384549, -122.08515152 ], [ 37.33862249, -122.08545696 ], [ 37.33879885, -122.08577472 ], [ 37.3389669, -122.08608946 ], [ 37.33913576, -122.08640269 ], [ 37.33930008, -122.08670293 ], [ 37.33947623, -122.08701088 ], [ 37.3396502, -122.08732093 ], [ 37.33981846, -122.08762326 ], [ 37.33998434, -122.08792937 ], [ 37.3401493, -122.08824042 ], [ 37.34031484, -122.08856086 ], [ 37.34046597, -122.08886286 ], [ 37.34061718, -122.08917878 ], [ 37.34077165, -122.08949679 ], [ 37.34092739, -122.08983097 ], [ 37.34107194, -122.09015057 ], [ 37.34121879, -122.09045668 ], [ 37.34137909, -122.09077234 ], [ 37.34154237, -122.09108423 ], [ 37.34171403, -122.09138934 ], [ 37.3418947, -122.091676 ], [ 37.34208941, -122.09195687 ], [ 37.34229154, -122.092223 ], [ 37.3424959, -122.09246482 ], [ 37.342708, -122.092712 ], [ 37.34291352, -122.09295692 ], [ 37.34312416, -122.09320284 ], [ 37.34332805, -122.09343444 ], [ 37.34353735, -122.09368045 ], [ 37.34374576, -122.09392 ], [ 37.34394974, -122.09415478 ], [ 37.34415677, -122.09439031 ], [ 37.34434595, -122.09463741 ], [ 37.34453978, -122.09489641 ], [ 37.34472464, -122.09516438 ], [ 37.3448932, -122.0954383 ], [ 37.34505141, -122.09572596 ], [ 37.34520782, -122.0960117 ], [ 37.34534964, -122.09631924 ], [ 37.34548953, -122.096638 ], [ 37.34562364, -122.09695274 ], [ 37.34576798, -122.09727888 ], [ 37.34590884, -122.09760787 ], [ 37.34604924, -122.0979434 ], [ 37.34619047, -122.09828781 ], [ 37.34633112, -122.09862728 ], [ 37.3464786, -122.09896549 ], [ 37.3466164, -122.09929791 ], [ 37.34676434, -122.09963352 ], [ 37.34690805, -122.09997509 ], [ 37.34705171, -122.10032243 ], [ 37.34719244, -122.1006624 ], [ 37.34733473, -122.10099349 ], [ 37.34747663, -122.10131879 ], [ 37.34762491, -122.1016513 ], [ 37.34777737, -122.10196336 ], [ 37.34794036, -122.10227399 ], [ 37.34812405, -122.10257499 ], [ 37.34831482, -122.10286198 ], [ 37.34851318, -122.10314001 ], [ 37.34872189, -122.10340186 ], [ 37.34894824, -122.1036539 ], [ 37.34918436, -122.10389589 ], [ 37.34941931, -122.10411164 ], [ 37.34966435, -122.10431859 ], [ 37.34991623, -122.10451573 ], [ 37.35016915, -122.1047086 ], [ 37.35042203, -122.10490214 ], [ 37.3506804, -122.10509685 ], [ 37.3509353, -122.10529449 ], [ 37.35119518, -122.1054944 ], [ 37.35145376, -122.10569934 ], [ 37.35170078, -122.10589849 ], [ 37.35194528, -122.10610938 ], [ 37.35218349, -122.10633762 ], [ 37.35240938, -122.10656821 ], [ 37.35262907, -122.10682025 ], [ 37.35283833, -122.10707414 ], [ 37.35304318, -122.1073468 ], [ 37.35322775, -122.10761167 ], [ 37.35340125, -122.10789012 ], [ 37.35357644, -122.10818206 ], [ 37.35373217, -122.10847987 ], [ 37.35388229, -122.10878137 ], [ 37.35402763, -122.10909116 ], [ 37.35416275, -122.10941512 ], [ 37.354285, -122.10973833 ], [ 37.35439853, -122.1100721 ], [ 37.35450989, -122.11040469 ], [ 37.35460422, -122.11074625 ], [ 37.35470108, -122.11109678 ], [ 37.35478615, -122.11144128 ], [ 37.35486926, -122.11178469 ], [ 37.3549592, -122.11213723 ], [ 37.35504792, -122.11248818 ], [ 37.35513836, -122.11282957 ], [ 37.35522226, -122.11317885 ], [ 37.35532071, -122.11352779 ], [ 37.35543424, -122.11386968 ], [ 37.35555758, -122.11420421 ], [ 37.35568444, -122.11452423 ], [ 37.35583234, -122.11484701 ], [ 37.35598347, -122.11516142 ], [ 37.35614335, -122.11546778 ], [ 37.35630592, -122.11577145 ], [ 37.35647419, -122.11607907 ], [ 37.35667204, -122.11636489 ], [ 37.35687073, -122.11663286 ], [ 37.35707534, -122.11689874 ], [ 37.35728082, -122.11715581 ], [ 37.3575003, -122.11741087 ], [ 37.35772158, -122.11764607 ], [ 37.35796495, -122.11787221 ], [ 37.35821377, -122.11808519 ], [ 37.35846644, -122.11829223 ], [ 37.35872263, -122.11848501 ], [ 37.3589945, -122.11866179 ], [ 37.35928216, -122.11883998 ], [ 37.35955814, -122.11901575 ], [ 37.35983897, -122.11918616 ], [ 37.36011952, -122.1193553 ], [ 37.36040727, -122.11952001 ], [ 37.36069305, -122.11969553 ], [ 37.3609743, -122.11986677 ], [ 37.36126096, -122.12003751 ], [ 37.36154377, -122.1202173 ], [ 37.36181958, -122.1204183 ], [ 37.36207862, -122.12062282 ], [ 37.36233305, -122.12084385 ], [ 37.36258266, -122.12108055 ], [ 37.36281941, -122.12133444 ], [ 37.36303768, -122.12160442 ], [ 37.36324345, -122.12188572 ], [ 37.36344328, -122.12218294 ], [ 37.36362588, -122.12248745 ], [ 37.36380169, -122.12279364 ], [ 37.36396061, -122.12310285 ], [ 37.36410876, -122.12341793 ], [ 37.36424153, -122.12374717 ], [ 37.36436332, -122.12407817 ], [ 37.36447237, -122.12441747 ], [ 37.36457081, -122.12476867 ], [ 37.36465673, -122.12512859 ], [ 37.36472923, -122.12549681 ], [ 37.3647884, -122.12586327 ], [ 37.36483488, -122.12623861 ], [ 37.36486694, -122.12661646 ], [ 37.36488463, -122.12699926 ], [ 37.36489573, -122.12737863 ], [ 37.36489494, -122.12775531 ], [ 37.36489561, -122.12814457 ], [ 37.36489536, -122.12851823 ], [ 37.36490102, -122.12889651 ], [ 37.364913, -122.12927755 ], [ 37.36492641, -122.12966111 ], [ 37.36495642, -122.13002966 ], [ 37.36500231, -122.13039762 ], [ 37.36505801, -122.13076299 ], [ 37.36513495, -122.13112023 ], [ 37.36522619, -122.13147671 ], [ 37.36533088, -122.13182204 ], [ 37.36543834, -122.13217241 ], [ 37.36554852, -122.13253006 ], [ 37.36565505, -122.13287858 ], [ 37.36576171, -122.13322476 ], [ 37.3658664, -122.13358057 ], [ 37.36597474, -122.1339342 ], [ 37.36607239, -122.13427694 ], [ 37.36617599, -122.13462026 ], [ 37.36627984, -122.13496408 ], [ 37.36637342, -122.13530514 ], [ 37.3664761, -122.13564763 ], [ 37.36657341, -122.13598643 ], [ 37.36667454, -122.13633075 ], [ 37.3667825, -122.13667173 ], [ 37.3668918, -122.13700784 ], [ 37.36700588, -122.13734664 ], [ 37.36714083, -122.13768569 ], [ 37.36728357, -122.13801602 ], [ 37.36743034, -122.13834434 ], [ 37.36759001, -122.13866201 ], [ 37.36776176, -122.13898061 ], [ 37.36794754, -122.13929619 ], [ 37.36813371, -122.13959391 ], [ 37.36833646, -122.13988803 ], [ 37.36854278, -122.1401674 ], [ 37.36876231, -122.14043713 ], [ 37.36898397, -122.14069152 ], [ 37.36921459, -122.14094005 ], [ 37.36945654, -122.1411796 ], [ 37.3697059, -122.14141823 ], [ 37.36994839, -122.1416339 ], [ 37.37019243, -122.14186189 ], [ 37.37043777, -122.14209172 ], [ 37.37068524, -122.14231367 ], [ 37.37092857, -122.14253931 ], [ 37.37117332, -122.14276269 ], [ 37.37142067, -122.14297886 ], [ 37.37167049, -122.14320232 ], [ 37.37190954, -122.14341883 ], [ 37.37215601, -122.14364204 ], [ 37.37240005, -122.14386038 ], [ 37.37263743, -122.14409064 ], [ 37.37287229, -122.14430781 ], [ 37.37311268, -122.14451887 ], [ 37.37336271, -122.14472699 ], [ 37.37361371, -122.14495984 ], [ 37.37385134, -122.14517802 ], [ 37.37409077, -122.14540877 ], [ 37.37433481, -122.14563986 ], [ 37.37457281, -122.14588663 ], [ 37.37481249, -122.14611939 ], [ 37.37503792, -122.14636347 ], [ 37.37527039, -122.14662055 ], [ 37.37550207, -122.14687494 ], [ 37.37572427, -122.14713511 ], [ 37.37595557, -122.14739872 ], [ 37.37618545, -122.14766024 ], [ 37.37641444, -122.14792309 ], [ 37.37664016, -122.14817958 ], [ 37.37686895, -122.14843858 ], [ 37.37709618, -122.14869624 ], [ 37.37732484, -122.14894979 ], [ 37.37755308, -122.14919429 ], [ 37.37778312, -122.14944148 ], [ 37.3780272, -122.14968145 ], [ 37.37828075, -122.14990349 ], [ 37.37854172, -122.15010976 ], [ 37.3787954, -122.15030297 ], [ 37.37906991, -122.15049139 ], [ 37.37933964, -122.15066314 ], [ 37.37961188, -122.15082139 ], [ 37.37989138, -122.15096748 ], [ 37.38018479, -122.15110721 ], [ 37.38048092, -122.15123277 ], [ 37.38078049, -122.15133956 ], [ 37.38107985, -122.15143117 ], [ 37.38139635, -122.15151398 ], [ 37.38170908, -122.15158724 ], [ 37.38201841, -122.1516569 ], [ 37.38232167, -122.15171758 ], [ 37.3826398, -122.15178036 ], [ 37.38294604, -122.15184264 ], [ 37.38325235, -122.15190458 ], [ 37.38355637, -122.15196543 ], [ 37.38386583, -122.15203945 ], [ 37.38417047, -122.1521117 ], [ 37.38447544, -122.1522008 ], [ 37.3847595, -122.15231454 ], [ 37.38505698, -122.15241395 ], [ 37.3853594, -122.15250213 ], [ 37.38560981, -122.15272559 ], [ 37.38587685, -122.15289608 ], [ 37.38612831, -122.15307537 ], [ 37.386369, -122.15330226 ], [ 37.38660109, -122.15352321 ], [ 37.38681491, -122.15376042 ], [ 37.38703695, -122.15399578 ], [ 37.38723661, -122.15426073 ], [ 37.38741594, -122.15453155 ], [ 37.38758433, -122.15481075 ], [ 37.38774539, -122.15510789 ], [ 37.38789928, -122.15540746 ], [ 37.38803876, -122.15572505 ], [ 37.38816025, -122.156047 ], [ 37.38827425, -122.1563775 ], [ 37.38837114, -122.1567204 ], [ 37.38845823, -122.15706146 ], [ 37.38852302, -122.15740629 ], [ 37.38858496, -122.15776739 ], [ 37.38863873, -122.158132 ], [ 37.38869141, -122.15849049 ], [ 37.38875059, -122.15884924 ], [ 37.38880101, -122.1592167 ], [ 37.38885423, -122.15958014 ], [ 37.38890729, -122.15994434 ], [ 37.38896215, -122.16030945 ], [ 37.38901726, -122.16067063 ] ]
```

I have tried using onthegomap.com but they export only in GPX and I have been unable to convert it to something like above.

Are there any databases for this or any websites that may facilitate this?

Comment: (if I understood correctly,) any geojson will be close enough to the format you are looking for. For example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-countries/master/data/countries.geojson

Comment: It's overkill, but the Overpass API will give you this: `https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node(35.10193405724606,-106.58935546875,35.11990857099681,-106.5673828125);<;);out;` -- you still have to dig a bit, but this is JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From comment)

(if I understood correctly,) any geojson will be close enough to the format you are looking for. For example:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-countries/master/data/countries.geojson

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you are but for the UK you can download postcode to lat/long tables from a variety of sources.

[UK postcodes to lat/long](https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm) - this site also has a variety of other countries.

You then seem to be asking how to [convert a csv into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy). Obviously for an app you don't want to have to load the csv every time as its a fairly expensive operation so you want to run it once and remember the result. This is an app programming question, however, rather than a question of where to source data.

Comment: Yes I asked on their as well

Comment: I'm not sure where your problem lies - you've got the csv and you've got a method to import a csv as an array. Which part of this are you struggling with?

Comment: im sorry i meant originally GPX, my apologies for that file type mistake.

Comment: Okay but have you attempted downloading it as a csv?